# Adsorption and distribution chromatography difference?

Tags: chromatography

Well, yes, that is the question. What is the difference between the *absorption chromatography* and *distribution chromatography*?

Answer (score 1):

**Adsorption Chromatography** = Utilizes a mobile liquid or gaseous phase that is adsorbed onto the surface of a stationary solid phase. The equilibriation between the mobile and stationary phase accounts for the separation of different solutes.

**Distribution Chromatography** (aka Liquid-Liquid extraction) = Due to its liquid stationary phase, the ingredients are only separated by their respective polarity, i.e. according to their distribution coefficient KD. Distribution chromatography is also ideal for the concentration of trace quantities. This is more closely related to Flash, Column, and Gas Chromatography.

Comment: Basically, the first is solid-liquid, the second liquid-liquid?
And if it is so, why does RP-chromatography belong to distribution chromatography and not to adsorption chromatography?